# RxAndroidBle, value should be in Hexadecimal

Tags: arrays, hex, rxandroidble

Values from the notification should be hexadecimal but I got decimal and negative values (with another app I got the good format) :

```
123 0 0 72 98 0  
124 0 0 39 97 0   
125 0 0 -2 95 0 
126 0 0 -50 94 0 
127 0 0 -105 93 0  
-128 0 0 88 92 0  
-127 0 0 18 91 0  
-126 0 0 -59 89 0 
-125 0 0 113 88 0 
-124 0 0 22 87 0 
-123 0 0 -76 85 0  
-122 0 0 76 84 0  
-121 0 0 -35 82 0  
-120 0 0 103 81 0
```

Do you know how can I get this in Hexadecimal form?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

The `RxAndroidBle` library emits a `byte[]` when a notification is received. A single `byte` value can be represented in a different ways.

The log you have presented is just printing the raw values according to Java specification. Java does not have a concept of unsigned values and every value that starts with a `1` bit is treated as a negative number. i.e. `0xA2` is equivalent to `-94`. `(0xA2 == -94) == true`

A simple way to display a value as a hex is to use `String.format()` i.e. `String.format("0x%2xh", byteValue)`

Most probably you wanted to ask a question: [How to convert a byte array to a hex String in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hex-string-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little method to convert a byte[] into a String that looks like `[02 FC 41 5A]` etc.:

```
static String byteArrayToHexDigits(final byte[] bytes) {
        int i;
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder( "[" );
        for( i = 0; i < (bytes.length-1); i++ ) {
            result.append(String.format( "%02X  ", bytes[i] ));
        }
        result.append(String.format( "%02X]", bytes[i] ));
        return result.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Note this will fail if the byte[] doesn't have at least 2 elements.